# Highcharts map trying to make it work

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to understand how highcharts map works since it's a great idea but I can't find anywhere some code sample to use as a starting point or to even understand how this works

I have checked those links
http://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm#Europe
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/studies
but nothing seems to work alone

If someone got a jsfiddle working that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Upcoming API for Highmaps: http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps I hope examples from there should be enough ;) Anyway, your example with Europe works fine for me.. Maps are under development so may sometime be 'offline' ;)

Comment: Thanks for your link, it will be useful. I'm trying to recreate those in local but I just cant figure out what is the function  maps/file.php?file=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/BlankMap-Europe.svg

Comment: You just need to pass SVG map to create chart

Comment: I do not have access to this function in local so I'm trying to find where it has been defined

Comment: @PawełFus, side note - the Meuse river demo is amazing. It is soon up for release?

Comment: It's available already ;)